# How to generate serializers/deserializers code for C#?

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

I'm a new entry in google protocol buffer.
I have a .proto file which defines all the protocol structures.

Since I use C# as programming language, I need to generate serializers/deserializers code for C#.

How can I do it?

Thank you

Comment: Be specific about your question. Your question lacks information to be answered.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net to a have library you can use under c# and https://protogen.marcgravell.com to generate a C# class file from a .proto file.

Answer (score 1):

Most protobuf tools come with a codegen piece. In the case of the google implementation, that would be `protoc` at the command-line. If you prefer protobuf-net, that would be `protogen`. For your convenience, both `protoc` and `protogen` are available to use here: https://protogen.marcgravell.com/

Once you have the model from the .proto, you just use the library-specific APIs. For example, with protobuf-net that would usually be:

```
var model = Serializer.Deserialize<YourRootType>(source);
```